# Does the distance of sound sources to the listener affect their playback time in the WebAudio API?

Tags: html, audio, html5-audio, web-audio-api

When I position a sound in 3D space with the AudioPanner and then play the sound, does it affect the playback time of the sound?

In example if one sound source is at **s1(1,0,0)** and the other sound source is at **s2(0,200,0)** with the listener positioned at **L(0,0,0)**. Then the **s1 would be played back first**, because the sound has only to travel the distance of 1 whereas the sound of s2 has to travel a distance of 200. So when they are played back at the same time, there should be a difference in playback time.

Answer (score 0):

Although there is the AudioListener attribute `speedOfSound`, it does only affect the doppler shift, according to the specification http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-webaudio-20131010/.

So you probably need to calculate yourself, but if someone knows more about this please contribute with another answer. :)